# OpenMP within a tight loop

Tags: io, openmp, shared-memory

In my loop each thread has its own file to write and after the loop is done the master process gathers all pieces in one big file, so it is not an issue.

```
#openmp parallel
{

  FILE *foutput; 
  foutput = fopen(...)

  i_min = ...   //I manually and equally share index 'i' between OpenMP threads   
  i_max = ...
     for (i = i_min;  i < i_max; ++i) 
        for (j = 0; j < 255; ++j) 
          for (k = 0; k < 255; ++k) {
             double value = some_function(i, j, k, var1, var2, var3);   
             fprintf(foutput, "%lf\n", value);

          }
 fclose(foutput);
}
```

'some_function' uses variables 'var1, var2, var3' which are of size (10MB) 
and which were defined before in master process. The point is that 'some_function' only **reads** variables, but changes nothing!

So this code works extremely slow and I don't understand why. Reading shared variables for openmp threads is totally fine and does not make any false sharing; maybe it is fprintf which makes all so slow and I should 
use binary files to write by blocks?

Comment: It is impossible to discuss vague performance observations based on pseudocode. Please provide a [mcve] (note if you are doing I/O this includes example input!). Make sure to include a clear specification of your system and how you build and execute the code as well as the specific performance results (numbers and measurement methodology!).

Comment: Also note that manual worksharing is almost never necessary or a good idea.